SPC56xx reference to unmapped memory SDA2 (0x80000000)
I'm reversing a binary built for the spc563m64 processor. The R2 (SDA2) register is set to 0x80008400 and this value is used to read and write the address space "near" that value throughout the code.
The problem is that according to the reference manual that space is "reserved" and there is no MMU entry containing it.
Is this a standard location for external eeprom or something along those lines? What am I missing?
